# Could not add card "/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so": agent refused operation

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I was using ubuntu 10.04 LTS as guest OS via VM VirtualBox. One day i get popup to upgrade it to ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I do so and in the process i face this problem.

I have a epass2003 token which i use to login to our servers. Now when i attempt to use it i get permission denied error.

I use following commands to add the card so i can access via ssh but i get the error/message. Please guide me to resolve this issue. Let me know if any additional information is required.

```
eval 'ssh-agent -s'
ssh-add -s /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so
```

Comment: Nobody ever responded?